# Error while connecting to my phppgadmin page

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu, phppgadmin

Every time, I try to go to my localhost/phppgadmin page, I always get this message, (i'm using ubuntu 16.04):

```
printHeader('', null, true); 
$rtl = (strcasecmp($lang['applangdir'], 'rtl') == 0); 
$cols = $rtl ? '*,'.$conf['left_width'] : $conf['left_width'].',*'; $mainframe = '' ?> 
printFooter(false); ?>
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Hello, whats the output you got if you try to do a phpinfo?

Comment: that's not a message it's some PHP code (although it doesn't look entirely valid PHP, but it's certainly PHP.)